# Azure SQL Private Link & Failover Group

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-private-dns

According to the MS Docs around private link and azure SQL failover groups, after creating private links to the primary and failover SQL server instances, subsequently creating the failover group should (I think?) add an entry to the private DNS zone so that applications can point directly to the failover group DNS, and not the original DNS entries added as per the private link process to the primary/secondary SQL servers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-configure-failover-group?tabs=azure-portal#use-private-link

After adding the failover group subsequent to adding private links, it does nothing to augment the private DNS zone with an entry which the applications can then use to privately consume the failover group endpoint, and the Failover group settings just show the FG DNS to connect to as per in a non-private link setup.

What is the expected outcome after following the documentation above? How should a private linked failover group DNS be accessed? As far as I can see it leaves you still needing to access the two previously created private link DNS entries?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Private Link allows you to associate a logical server to a specific private IP address within the virtual network and subnet. This is useful when a Failover Group DNS group cannot be to reach, maybe during a node break of interconnection between nodes (it may be when a fiber fails).

When Failover Group is Ok, you have a full connection to the someone of replicas - primary or secondary - thru the DNS name of the listener.

However, if it's necessary to access to one of Azure SQL Server database node privately thru a client program, e.g., a node called *myserver.database.windows.net* , we may use SQL Management Studio and you will need to provide the following information:

```
    **Setting**     **Value**
    Server type     *Database Engine*
    Server name     *myserver.database.windows.net*
    User name       *yourusername@servername*
    Password        *yourpassword*
```

The *servername* is gotten thru the command:

```
    SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```